# SimpleXML child element attributes

Tags: php, xml, parsing, simplexml

```
<form action='' method='post'>
<input type='text' name='location'>
<input type='submit' name='submit'>
</form>

<?php

if(isset($_POST['submit']) && !empty($_POST['location'])) {

$input = $_POST['location'];
$url = 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?q='.strtolower($input).'&mode=xml';
$xml = file_get_contents($url, false);
$xml = simplexml_load_string($xml);
echo '<b>Viewing Weather For:</b> '. $xml->location->name;
echo '<b>Temperature:</b> '. $xml->forecast->children('temperature')->attributes('value');

}
```

Weather API: http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?q=london,uk&mode=xml

I am trying to get the value of the temperature

```
echo '<b>Temperature:</b> '. $xml->forecast->children('temperature')->attributes('value');
```

This is where im stuck

I would really appreciate your answers :)

Comment: The question is, _which_ of the temperature's are you looking for? There's more then 1....

Comment: First value in the XML document

Comment: The least cumbersom/easiest way would be a bit of `XPath`: `$xml->xpath('forecast/time[1]/temperature/@value')`.

Comment: please add a snippet of XML to your question, the link will maybe one day be gone, then your question doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the `value` attribute of the first occurence of the `temperature` node, do:

```
$result = $xml->forecast[0]->time[0]->temperature["value"];
```

To take `<time>` into account, use `xpath`:

```
$results = $xml->xpath("//time");
```

this will select all `time` nodes, now loop:

```
foreach ($results as $result)
    echo "temperature for $result[from] to $result[to]: {$result->temperature['value']}<br />";
```

see it working: http://codepad.viper-7.com/wuUbEv